# Coldfusion cfdocument pdf conversion javascript not working

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have a `_reports_full.cfm` file which has all the html and also have a small javascript which then renders the page numbers on each page and also calculates page total and displays that. Also, the converted pdf is then emailed as an attachment. Now, I have cfdocument like this

```
<cfdocument format="pdf"
    backgroundvisible="yes"
    orientation="#URL.orientation#"
    marginLeft="0.25" marginRight="0.25"
    marginTop="0"
    saveAsName = "PDFGenerator.pdf"
    marginBottom="0"
    fontEmbed="false"
    pageType="letter" pageWidth="8" pageHeight="11" unit="in" localurl="yes">
        <cfset num = 1>
            <cfloop index="i" list="#theCode#" delimiters="|||">
                <cfif num GT 1>
                    <cfdocumentitem type = "pagebreak"/>
                </cfif>
            #i#
            <cfset num = num + 1>
            </cfloop>
    </cfdocument>
```

Variable `theCode` is a `cfhttp.fileContent` to the url for this `_reports_full.cfm` file.

And Javascript code is below which is also included in _reports.full.cfm,

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pageCnt").value;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pageCnt").value;
    if (document.getElementById("p3")) document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pageCnt").value;
    if (document.getElementById("p4")) document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pageCnt").value;
    if (document.getElementById("p5")) document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pageCnt").value;
    if (document.getElementById("p6")) document.getElementById("p6").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pageCnt").value;
    if (document.getElementById("p7")) document.getElementById("p7").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pageCnt").value;
</SCRIPT>
```

I am able to see the page numbers and total in browser(I have 2 options in my application, one is to view the printable in browser and other is to email it in pdf and html format, now I should mention that html formatted email also doesn't display the page numbers or total).
Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I follow that. What exactly is the issue? What is the code doing, and what did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Will javascript execute if the page's HTML is read into memory?  You may want to consider using "jsoup" to perform jQuery-like replacements to modify the HTML on-the-fly.